# SEHException External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, .net

I am using VS 2010 with MS Access 2010. Microsoft Access Database engine 2010 is also installed. OS version is Window 7 Enterprise with 64 bit Operating system.

Below is my code where i am getting the exception. Also i paste the stack track.

```
DCXManagerTableAdapters.AppDefaultOptionTableAdapter dataAdapter = new DCXManagerTableAdapters.AppDefaultOptionTableAdapter();

dataAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = DB.ConnectionString;

if (dataAdapter.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

{dataAdapter.Connection.Open();} \* Here i am getting exception
```

> Inner Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
>   (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    at
>   Branson.DataAccess.Providers.GraphTabProvider.GetAppDefaultOption() in
>   D:\BRANSON-SVN\Solution\Branson.DataAccess\Providers\GraphTabProvider.cs:line
>   180    at Branson.Controller.GraphTabController.GetAppDefaultOption()
>   in
>   D:\BRANSON-SVN\Solution\Branson.Controller\GraphTabController.cs:line
>   37    at Branson.DCXManager.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in
>   D:\BRANSON-SVN\Solution\Branson.DCXManager\Branson.DCXManager\App.xaml.cs:line
>   174    at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)

Comment: It looks like the error is related to opening the connection to the database.  What is your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

If this connection was once working and has stopped it may be due to an open handle to the file.

You need to make sure there is no other process holding a handle to your access file or excel file.

You can do this easily using Process Explorer, this is a debugging application which is part of the Sysinternals Suite.

You can download Process Explorer as a stand alone application here: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

1. Open the 'Process Monitor'
2. Select the 'Find' tab in the main toolbar
3. Select 'Find Handle or DLL...'
4. Enter the file you wish to query i.e. 'MyExcel.xls' and a list of
   all handles to your file will appear.
5. Next, close whatever application is holding you file, and try
   running your application again.